# Why does this simple C code print the addresses in the reverse order ? (For Ex. 4214868 4214864)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Prints the addresses of `i` and `j`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i,j;
void main()
{
    printf("%u %u",&i,&j); 
    getch();
}
```

---

Output:

```
4214868 4214864
```

Comment: Because `C` compiler reads from right to left.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behaior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. To print addresses, cast them to `void*` and use `%p` specifier. Also usage of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, should be avoided and standard `int main(void)` should be used in hosted environment.

Comment: The compiler has no obligations to place variables in memory in any particular order. It could be 12054 and 999924 just as easily

Comment: You seem surprised to see this. Can you elaborate a bit more about what you thought was going to happen and why?

Comment: *UB*, but obviously your implementation has a downward growing stack.

Comment: @dhke Typically stack won't be used because `i` and `j` have static storage duration.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ah, I overlooked that they where outside of `main()`. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i,j;
void main()
```

This is wrong. (That's a slight oversimplification, but it's close enough.) The correct declaration is `int main(void)`.

```
{
    printf("%u %u",&i,&j);
```

The `"%u"` format requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. Passing an `int*` pointer value causes undefined behavior.  The correct way to print the addresses is:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void*)&i, (void*)&j);
```

Note the `\n`: a program's output should end with a newline.

```
    getch();
```

There is no `getch()` function declared in `<stdio.h>`. If you didn't get at least a warning on that call, you should find out how to enable better diagnostics in your compiler.

You're probably trying to call the `getch()` function declared in the Windows (and DOS?) specific `<conio.h>` header. This makes your program unnecessarily non-portable.

```
}
```

As for the values it's printing, the C standard says nothing about the relative addresses of variables. The compiler is free to allocate them in any way it likes. And there's no good reason for you to *care* whether `i` is allocated before or after `j` in memory.

Comment: The output of an address need not even be integer numeric.  _Could_ be "ABD0:BEEF" or "red".

Comment: @chux Oh my mistake it's outside Main I thought it was inside. Well in that case where the compiler puts this in memory is completely arbitrary. It usually behaves in a similar fashion to how a function would build it's stack but that is completely arbitrary and probably not worth mentioning.

Comment: @arduic: It's completely arbitrary regardless of where they're defined.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print addresses with the format `%u`, it invokes undefined behavior.  One good reason for this is addresses might not be the same size as `unsigned int`.

Change your code to use the `%p` format, which expects addresses as `void *`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, j;
void main() {
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)&i, (void*)&j); 
    getch();
}
```

If you absolutely want decimal output, you can convert the addresses to `uintptr_t`, as use macros from `<inttypes.h>` to convert the values to decimal format, provided your C library is C99 conformant:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i, j;
void main(void) {
    printf("%"PRIuPTR" %"PRIuPTR"\n", (uintptr_t)&i, (uintptr_t)&j); 
    getchar();
}
```

Note that your code exhibits a number of bad practices:

- defining global variables with short names such as `i` and `j` is **very** bad style, leads to confusion and bugs.
- the prototype for `main` is either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent.
- `getch()` is not a standard function.  It is a pity your Windows hosted development environment does not keep the terminal window open for you to see your programs output.
- returning `0` from `main` is not strictly necessary, but considered good style.

Regarding your question, the actual addresses at which global variables are set by the compiler/linker are not defined by the standard. No assumption should be made as to how they are determined nor in which order variables are stored in memory.  As a matter of fact, on some architectures such as OS/X, these addresses are randomized at runtime, so the output of your program can vary from one execution to another, running the same executable file, on the same machine.

Comment: How does this answers the actual question or order?